# Installing from USB to a new HD - Drive not found

Tags: installation, partitioning, format

I just bought a new hard drive and attached it to my Windows 7 machine to format it (NTFS) and create a single, primary partition.

Then I put it into the machine I want to install Ubuntu on and ran the set-up from USB.

I get through to the point of chosing the storage location, then the install errors out, saying that it has unexpectly stopped. On the screen it lists only "dev/sda" but no volumes are displayed. If I click any button on this screen (other than "Back" or "Cancel" the error appears. After I send in the error report, the screen drops to a console display that accepts no input.

Do I need to reformat the drive as something other than NTFS? Or do I need to set up a different kind of partition, or remove the partition? I'm just not sure what the initial state of the hard drive should be in order for Ubuntu to install to it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to reformat the drive as something other than NTFS?

Yes, Ubuntu uses a Linux based permissions system and NTFS does not understand it. Ubuntu needs to be installed onto an `ext` formatted filesystem. `ext4` is the newest version.

> and create a single, primary partition.

This will not work. You need to use partition magic (in windows) or gparted to create a second (can be unallocated) partition. If you have that you will get extra options in the installer (ie. amongst others: "use unallocated space").

> Example as shown in Windows disc manager.

- C:  NTFS Has Windows.
- unallocated space.

> Example from Ubuntu installer.

- sda1  NTFS Has Windows.
- unallocatedspace.

You then can use the installer to change the unallocated space into partitions with mountpoint `/` (everything but 2-4Gb) and swap (that is the 2-4Gb).

Comment: Thank you. I will try this later tonight when I have access to the system and report back.

Comment: No problem. I was still editing when you posted this comment :) If it is acceptable in its current form do not forget to upvote. Otherwise feel free to ask for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I happened to have just downloaded Acronis Easy Migrate for another project and was able to use the demo version to format the drive as ext3, in two, unallocated partitions.

When I put the disk back into the machine and ran the installer, it worked, and I was able to install to the drive.

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like I spoke too soon. I don't know what's going on. I'm running Ubuntu and I removed the USB drive. But when I go to "Computer" I see "250 GB Hard Disk" and "File System."

Comment: I can open the "File System" but when I click on "250 GB Hard Disk" I get the message, "Unable to mount location: Can't mount file."

Comment: (I guess when I hit the Enter key it considers that the end of my comment...a bit annoying.)

Comment: Anyway, I'm not sure why I can't double-click to open "250 GB Hard Drive" since that's what I thought the USB installed installed Ubuntu to. Is it just running in the RAM or something?

Comment: When I view Properties on "250 GB Hard Disk" I see: Name: 250 GB Hard Disk, Type: unknown type (application/octet-stream), Size: unknown, Location: computer:///, Volume: unknown, Accessed: unknown, Modified: unknown.....Very weird and confusing.